# custom validation with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I am finding it hard to do some validation with my custom made validator.

Here it is:

```
class SomeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.baggage > options[:max]
      record.errors[:baggage] << "is over #{options[:max]}."   
    end
  end
end
```

Now I am trying to send it this number which needs to be read from another model. This is my validated model:

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flight
  validates :baggage, :some => {:max => flight.max_allowance}
end
```

Where flight is the other model, and max_allowance is the number I want to read. This doesn't work of course.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Proc as argument. Something like this:

```
validates :baggage, :some => {:max => Proc.new{|record| record.flight.max_allowance}}
```

Comment: now I got this error:

`comparison of BigDecimal with Proc failed`